# Widget layout update broken

Tags: magento, widget

In Magento 1.8.1.0 the button for layout update at **CMS > Widgets** does not work any longer. According to the Chrome Developer Tools it has to do with javascript and the notice I get is:

Uncaught ReferenceError: WidgetInstance is not definedonclick @ (index):997

What would cause such an error?

Thanks,

Marcel